# How to open a Lotus Notes Database on a network share?

Tags: com, lotus-notes

I am trying to interact with a Notes database (my personal mail file), via C# and am stuck right out of the gate, trying to open the database with the following code:

```
        string sNotesSourceFolder = "$Inbox";
        string sUserName = "scady";
        string sMailFile = @"NotesMail_FDrive\ARchives\" + sUserName + ".nsf";         
        string sServerName = @"Answers1/Answers";
        string sPassword = "xxxxxx";


        //Creating the notes session 
        NotesSession session = new NotesSession();
        session.Initialize(sPassword);
        NotesDatabase NotesDb = session.GetDatabase(sServerName, sMailFile, false);

        //If the database is not already open then open it. 
        if (!NotesDb.IsOpen)
        {
            NotesDb.Open();
        }
```

calling session.GetDatabase() with the server name and path the the nsf file returns null which, apparently means it could not open the db.

I am running this code locally, against a Notes server called "Answers1/Answers".  I am now thinking based on From the Notes server, the nsf files are located on a network fileshare of "NotesMail_FDrive\ARchives\xyz.nsf".

Comment: Just be aware that accessing NSFs on a network share is an unsupported configuration. This means while it should work, it has never been tested/built for this setup.

Comment: After speaking with our Notes admin, he explained that it "took some work" to get Domino to be able to use nsfs on a network file share, so I am now wondering if this is the problem. The mail file is not on the same machine as the domino server.  Any ideas?

Comment: If the Notes client can open the database, then a program written with Notes APIs should be able to open the database using the exact same server name and pathname that the client sees, as long as you are using the same ID file for both attempts.  How about trying an experiment? just try opening names.nsf or any other database located in the server's data directory which you have at least read access to.  If that fails, then you have an access problem of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the server on which the file resides a Notes server or just a network share?

If it's a network share, you need the drive mapping, but sServerName would be "" to get to a "local" drive. I'm assuming Notesdata1 is a directory on X, so if it's the drive name, remove it.

```
string sMailFile = @"X:\Notesdata1\NotesMail\ARchives\scady.nsf";
string sServerName = @"";
```

If it's a Notes server AND Notesdata1 is the data directory for the Notes server, then

```
string sMailFile = @"NotesMail\ARchives\scady.nsf";
string sServerName = @"Answers1/Answers";
```

Comment: It would appear as though your second option above should be the winning solution, but still no luck.  I am starting to think that this has to do with what has been described as an unsupported configuration where the mail file is located on a machine other than the notes server itself.

Comment: If the mail file is not on the Notes server, it's closer to the former than the latter. You're not interfacing with the Notes server at all. What directory is the data directory as listed in the Notes.ini file for your machine? Is the archive directory in this path?

Comment: Trying setting sMailFile = "X:\ARchives\scady.nsf" when X: is mapped to NotesMail_FDrive

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded.  It looks (shamefully) like this was an issue with authentication all along?  If I open the notes client on the machine that runs this code before running, then everything works fine - even if I then close the client.  I am not entirely sure why this is the case.  Marking this as answered anyway as this answer correctly describes the settings required to access a notes db stored on a network file share, which was the main point of my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't notice this on the first pass...

The value for sMailFile should not be "\10.10.10.71\notesdata1\NotesMail\ARchives\scady.nsf". The other two values that you have commented out are also wrong.  The arguments for getDatabase are the Domino server's distinguished name, and a relative path.  No server IP, no volume, and no "file:" prefix.  Just something like this: `"archives\scady.nsf"`.  It should be exactly what you see for the path when you open up the database in your Notes client and bring up the database properties dialog.

**Previous Answer**

Your sServername variable contains the Domino server's distinguished name, as it should.

But why are you using File.Exists?  The Domino server wants exclusive access to all of the files in its data tree.  If you are actually successfully accessing the file on the Domino server via a filesystem call, then perhaps you are  locking the Domino server out of accessing it.

But also: where are you running this code?  Are you running it on the same computer, and under the same account that you normally use to read your email?  Or on a different computer and account?

Comment: I was only using File.Exists to ensure that it was not a problem with "seeing" the file from the call.  It can/should be removed once I get this running.

Comment: And, I am running the code from the same computer and under the same account that I use to read my mail through the notes client.

Comment: Okay. I have updated my answer.  But if it is not sufficient, can you please update your code to show what the code you actually want to use is?  The other big problem in the code is that every single one of the values you are assigning to sMailFile in the commented and non-commented lines is wrong.

Comment: I think your issue is trying t access a server based file as if it were local. You SHOULD NOT do this. Rather open it on the server with the relative path from the servers data directory.

Comment: Please see my update to the original post re. the environment I am running this code in.  I have updated the code in my question to the latest version - not working.  Thanks all.

Comment: When you open that exact database in the Notes client, and you bring up the Database Properties dialog, what do you see for the Filename?  is it really NotesMail_FDrive\ARchives\xyz.nsf?

Comment: @Newbs The file is just on a network drive, not on the Notes server.

Comment: @DavidNavarre - Then you should open as if it were local, IE the server is blank. You may also be better off trying it with a mapped drive to the file share so the actual file name is R:\Archives\xyz.nsf.  This is a poor practice since Notes is designed to support truly local files OR files stored on a server. Files stored on a fie share are a hybrid that Notes tries to avoid.

Comment: @DavidNavarre It's not really clear that he's doing that.  The question explicitly says: I am running this code locally, against a Notes server called "Answers1/Answers", and he included it in the code.

Comment: The question was badly worded. In his comment of Nov 9 at 17:16 to my answer, he stated "the mail file is located on a machine other than the notes server itself." Should we edit the question to clarify for people searching this in the future?

Comment: And yet, in that same answer he said that your 'second answer' was the right one, but that one specifies the server name.  That sure led me off on the wrong track!  I do think an edit would be appropriate.